# Lebesgue integral at infinity of this function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to take the Lebesgue integral of the following function over $\mathbb R$, where $1\le p\lt q\le \infty$.

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^{-1/p},  & x\ge1 \\[2ex]
0, & x<1
\end{cases}$

And I have that:

$\int_\mathbb R|f|^qdm=\int_1^\infty|f|^qdm=\int_1^\infty x^{-q/p}dx=[\frac1{1-q/p}x^{1-q/p}]_1^\infty=\frac{-1}{1-q/p}$

How, exactly, does the evaluation at "$\infty$" disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(L)\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-q/p}dx&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(L)\int_{1}^{N}x^{-q/p}dx\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(R)\int_{1}^{N}x^{-q/p}dx\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{N^{1-q/p}}{1-q/p}-\dfrac{1}{1-q/p}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{1-q/p},
\end{align*}
where $(L)$ stands for Lebesgue integral, $(R)$ stands for Riemann integral, and the first equality comes from Monotone Convergence Theorem.